# xcode navigation bar button state

Tags: swift, xcode, button, state

I have an edit button - UIBarButtonItem

[image]

which disappears from screen when it was clicked

[image]

and appears when cancel button was clicked

[image]

As you can see, the state of edit button stays selected after appearing.
How can I programmatically change Navigation bar buttons state to normal state? Or suggest me a better way.

here is my project code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, introductionDelegate {

var navBarEditButton: UIBarButtonItem?
var navBarDeleteButton: UIBarButtonItem?
var navBarCancelButton: UIBarButtonItem?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navBarEditButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Edit", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(editObjectsAction))
    self.navBarDeleteButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Delete", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(deleteObjectsAction))
    self.navBarCancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(cancelAction))

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [navBarEditButton!]
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@objc private func editObjectsAction(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [navBarCancelButton!, navBarDeleteButton!]
}

@objc private func cancelAction(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [navBarEditButton!]
}

@objc private func deleteObjectsAction(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

}
```

Comment: Code above looks fine. With which device are you testing? please check for navBarEditButton throughout the other part of the code. may be you are disabling it at some other point.

Comment: Testing with iPhone 8, and in whole code navBarEditButton meets only four times.

Comment: okay fine, I was just conforming to be sure about the disabled state from other part, but was not the reason in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a new function

```
func refreshNavBarButton (navBarButton: inout UIBarButtonItem) {
    navBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: navBarButton.title, style: navBarButton.style, target: navBarButton.target, action: navBarButton.action)
}
```

And I call it every time before navigation bar button showing

```
    refreshNavBarButton(navBarButton: &navBarEditButton!)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [navBarEditButton!]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create `UIBarButtonItem` with `UIButton` and handle the state on that button. With this, you change the UIBarButtonItem style but just check whether you get the intended result.

```
let myButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 300, width: 100, height: 40)) // handle state on this button
self.navBarEditButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: myButton)
```